# imagesc plot to matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I would like to save in a matrix the plot that imagesc returns.
How can I do that?
All I know that imagesc returns a handle and I don't know what to do with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data for `imagesc` is stored in the `CData` property, so use this to extract it:

```
X = get(h, 'CData');
```

assuming `h` is your handle.

Now `X` contains your image data, and you can save it to a file, for instance:

```
save somefile.mat X
```

Comment: for completeness, I'd add this assumes a `h=imagesc(...)` was used, otherwise the `h` doesn't mean a lot.

Comment: @natan it's implied that it's the handle that the OP mentioned in his question, _i. e._ obtained by `imagesc`, but thanks for the clarification.

Comment: First, Thanks. But I already tried that and 'cdata' contains the original image, not what imagesc plots.

Comment: @boshnak What's the difference between the original image and the one `imagesc` plots (except the re-scaling)? Can't you extract the original image and scale it "manually"?

Comment: @EitanT I tried to scale it manually but my results weren't so good. I would be happy if you could explain how to do so...

Comment: @boshnak `imagesc` scales the data to the range of the current colormap. To scale an image `I` to a range [a, b], do `Iscaled = ((I - min(I)) * (b - a)) / (max(I) - min(I))`.