# Get the matrix after imagesc?

Tags: matlab

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [imagesc plot to matrix in matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14111371/imagesc-plot-to-matrix-in-matlab)
>   [Scale Matrix to a new range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14363723/scale-matrix-to-a-new-range)

I have:

```
I = imread('image.tif');
```

At this point I can easly print the pixel with cord 100,100 by doing I(100,100)
Now I scale to image to fit the range `0.5...0.9`

```
imagesc(I,[0.5 0.9]);
colormap('gray');
```

Is there any way to get the new matrix I ? (with pixel values from 0.5 to 0.9)

If i do

```
I  = imagesc(I,[0.5 0.9]);
```

I only get the handler to image object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the image data from an image plot with:

```
A = rand(100,100);
I = imagesc(A, [.5 .9]);
B = get(I, 'CData');
```

Predicting from your previous question: [Scale Matrix to a new range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14363723/scale-matrix-to-a-new-range) I expect that `B` won't be you want. In fact `B` will be identical to `A`. This can be verified with:

```
all(all(A==B))
```

The second argument to `imagesc` doesn't scale the values in the provided matrix rather it scales the colormap.

Comment: slayton thanks for claryfing that! another +1...

Answer (score 2):

Try the `getimage` [command](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/getimage.html):

```
A = rand(100,100);
I = imagesc(A, [.5 .9]);
B = getimage(gca);
```