# Matlab, How to get the result generated by imagesc?

Tags: image, matlab, scale, normalize

I read some similar article, but they are not what I want.
[Get the matrix after imagesc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14364239/get-the-matrix-after-imagesc/14364434#14364434)
[imagesc plot to matrix in matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14111371/imagesc-plot-to-matrix-in-matlab)

**My Problem**
I have a matrix `A` with all elements are double.
I do `imagesc(A)` and then I have an image.
Now, I want to get the matrix that make the image. **How can I do that?**

From those articles, if I do

```
I = imagesc(A)
B = get(I, 'CData')
```

Then `B == A` that is not what I want.

Comment: Check [getimage](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/images/ref/getimage.html).

Comment: You said what you don't want, but it is not clear to me exactly what you want. What is a 'matrix that make the image'??

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make it clear. What I know is that imagesc(A) will scale the data and display those data as an image. What I want is to get those data after scaling. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To scale the image in the same way as imagesc do the following

```
Amin = min(A(:));
Amax = max(A(:));
A_scaled = (A - Amin)/(Amax - Amin);
```

To prove that the scaled image is what imagesc does internally then try this

```
imagesc(A,[Amin Amax]);
pause
imagesc(A_scaled);
```

Comment: @twerdster You probably meant `image` on the last line?

Comment: If I do `A = rand(100,100); "code provided by twerdster" image(A_scaled);` then I will get an image with all blue, how can I get the same figure by image()?

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in a simpler way. I tried my code in Octave.

```
colormap gray;
h=imshow(F,[]);
B=get(h, 'CData');
```

Comment: F is the original array and B is the scaled data.

Comment: in MATLAB, both `F` and `B` are the original matrix. The scaling is only done implicitly in the view without affecting the data.