# What is the equivalent of imagesc in OpenCV

Tags: python, matlab, opencv, numpy

What would be the equivalent of [`imagesc`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imagesc.html#f25-762613) in OpenCV?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get the nice colors in imagesc you have to play around with OpenCV a little bit. In OpenCV 2.46 there ss a colormap option.

This is code I use in c++. Im sure its very similar in Python.

```
mydata.convertTo(display, CV_8UC1, 255.0 / 10000.0, 0); 
applyColorMap(display, display, cv::COLORMAP_JET);
imshow("imagesc",display);
```

The image data or matrix data is stored in `mydata`. I know that it has a maximum value of 10000 so I scale it down to 1 and then multiply by the range of CV_8UC1 which is 255. If you dont know what the range is the best option is to [first convert your matrix in the same way as Matlab does it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18251044/matlab-how-to-get-the-result-generated-by-imagesc/18253149#18253149).

**EDIT**

Here is a version which automatically normalizes your data.

```
float Amin = *min_element(mydata.begin<float>(), mydata.end<float>());
float Amax = *max_element(mydata.begin<float>(), mydata.end<float>());
Mat A_scaled = (mydata - Amin)/(Amax - Amin);
A_scaled.convertTo(display, CV_8UC1, 255.0, 0); 
applyColorMap(display, display, cv::COLORMAP_JET);
imshow("imagesc",display);
```

Comment: +1 perhaps you should generalize the code by using [`cv::normalize`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#normalize) to normalize the image to the range of its data type, just like you did in MATLAB in the linked post

Comment: @twerdtser: I think you should changed by `Mat A_scaled = (mydata - Amin)/(Amax - Amin)`

Answer (score 2):

It's close to `imshow` in matlab.

It depends on modules you use in python:

```
import cv2
import cv2.cv as cv

I_cv2 = cv2.imread("image.jpg")
I_cv = cv.LoadImage("image.jpg")

#I_cv2 is numpy.ndarray norm can be done easily
I_cv2_norm = (I_cv2-I_cv2.min())/(I_cv2.max()-I_cv2.min())
cv2.imshow("cv2Im scaled", I_cv2_norm)

#Here you have to normalize your cv iplimage as explain by twerdster to norm
cv.ShowImage("cvIm unscaled",I_cv)
```

The best way I think to be close to imagesc, is to use `cv2.imread` which load image as numpy.ndarray and next use `imshow` function from `matplotlib.pyplot` module:

```
import cv2
from matplolib.pyplot import imshow, show
I = cv2.imread("path")
#signature:
imshow(I, cmap=None, norm=None, aspect=None, interpolation=None,
             alpha=None, vmin=None, vmax=None, origin=None, extent=None,
             **kwargs)
```

Here you can choose whatever you want if normalized or your clims (scale)...

Comment: note that `imagesc` will also appropriately scale the image. Say in OpenCV you have a `CV_64F` image with values outside the range `[0,1]`, you'll need to map them to the expected range before showing the image